# Why font-size in body does not affect font in a table unless I add 1em?

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

```
<style>
body {
    font-size: 14px;
}
</style>

<body>
Text outside table.
<table>
    <tr><td>Text inside table.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text inside table.</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Text inside table.</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
```

I'm trying to specify base font size for my website so in other places I can use percentage or em to specify the size.

The html code above, without `body` style the font will be at the same size. However, why with `font-size` in `body` style like above, only "Text outside table." got affected by the size change? Isn't everything is encapsulated in `<body>` ?

I need to add

```
table {
    font-size: 1em;
}
```

In order to make font in my table follow `body`'s font-size. Why this is not the case as with my other `<div>`s in my page? Those `<div>`s did follow `body`'s `font-size` nicely.

Comment: Not seeing it: http://jsfiddle.net/tAypJ/ You must have another rule for the table that's interfering (right click -> inspect element to see the CSS rules.)

Comment: That's strange O_o jsfiddle returns different result.In Chrome (OSX Lion) it looked like this : https://www.dropbox.com/s/6dvx640oornxauq/Screenshot%202013-12-01%2020.13.47.png

Comment: Maybe you have an extension or something that interferes. Try in incognito mode or inspect the element to see what CSS rules apply to the table.

Comment: There is "user agent stylesheet" striking out my font-size and replace it with "medium" gotta look into it..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your page is being rendered in [Quirks Mode](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/quirks-mode.html), probably because it lacks a `doctype` string at the start or starts with a `doctype` string interpreted as nonstandard.

It is part of quirks mode, even in the limited sense of “HTML5 quirks mode” (which tries to standardize some common quirks) that tables no do not inherit font properties. This is being formally defined in HTML 5, in a clause about [rendering tables](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#tables). The definition there uses the `initial` keyword, which isn’t quite standard yet, but it simply means the initial value for a property as defined in CSS specifications. For `font-size`, it is indeed `medium`.

If this is an old page, it is best to live with the quirks and just explicitly declare font properties for tables, e.g. with

```
body, table { font-size: 14px }
```

(not that I would ever recommend such inflexibility).

If this is about a new page you are creating, put `<!doctype html>` at the start and use “standard” HTML and CSS consistently.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that Chrome's default CSS style "user agent stylesheet" **for table** is using `font-size: medium;` and that is applied to my `table` (Which does not have any `font-size`)

In consequence, that CSS rule are used to ignore my `body`'s `font-size` because `table` is deeper in hierarchy, the `medium` size will take priority.

I guess there is no better way to prevent it other than adding `font-size` style to table (Ideally with `1em` value). With a style applied, the default CSS rule has no chance to be used.